# Что лучше: добавить кнопку button или отслеживать нажатие через ивент IPointerClickHandler

Tags: unity3d, оптимизация, button, ui

В button отслеживается сразу и нажатие и отжатие и т.д.. Это значит, что через ивенты реализация менее затратна?

Comment: Все `Selectable` обрабатывают как минимум: `IPointerDownHandler`, `IPointerUpHandler`, `IPointerEnterHandler`, `IPointerExitHandler`, `ISelectHandler`, `IDeselectHandler`, вот только "ЗАТРАТАМИ" это не назвать, все равно что пытаться сэкономить на спичках.